# Is there a way to make C# Application automatically adjust on computer .net framework version?

Tags: c#, .net

I made a local messenger app in C# . the problem is that some of the computers in the office have .net framework older version. Those computers run Windows XP

Is there a way that the app automatically use the computer .net framework version? Thanks.

Comment: What if your application uses a .NET Framework feature that isn't available in an older version of the framework? It won't work, will it? You should either install the correct version of the framework on the target computers, or build against the minimum common version. The latter might require you to rewrite some of your code to match the feature set of that version.

Comment: What do you mean? What older framework? Is it a .NET 4.5.x version? Or an unsupported 2.x? `some of the computers` why not upgrade them to a *supported* version? Or are they using unsupported OS versions like Windows XP?

Comment: Is anyone in the office still use Windows 7 (or, shudder, below)? If not, just target 4.5, all currently supported Windows OS have .NET 4.x that all should run app targeted at 4.5 without fuss.

Comment: Unless those machines run Windows XP you could rewrite the application in .NET (Core) 5, create a self-contained package and deploy that. .NET 5 is in a better state of support than running on Windows XP

Comment: When I installed the latest .net framework to other computers. It only says that "This computer does not support the version"

Comment: @Martheen Windows 7 runs .NET 4.5+ just fine. Only XP is limited to .NET 4

Comment: @JohnPatrickCunanan that means the computer isn't supported, period. Because it runs Windows XP. That OS is past its end-of-life. The only *responsible* solution is to upgrade it. Quite simply, it's wide open to all malware released in the last 10 years

Comment: @JohnPatrickCunanan in the meantime, you can use packages like `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` to add `async/await` to .NET 4.0 applications. BTW you still haven't explained what the problem is

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks man! and just I checked some computers here are still windows xp.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! Now I know. Godbless

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm referring the built-in .NET Framework that comes by default, assuming those PCs are either don't get online or have the Windows Update disabled.. Because otherwise all of those should've already get the .NET 4.8 through Windows update by now.

Comment: @JohnPatrickCunanan what are the OS  and .NET versions? Without that, we are all just guessing. Although such questions have been asked before, and the answer is clear. After all, Windows XP is 17 years old

Comment: Windows XP should not be used at all, period, end of story. It is a virus factory. Tell your boss to upgrade

Comment: If someone is crazy enough to still be running Windows XP 7 years after it went end-of-life then, frankly, the fact your software doesn't work on those computers is the fault of the owner of the computer, not yours. They're being highly irresponsible by running crucial software that is so out of date. There must be a lot of other useful software that those machines can't run by now either, not to mention the risk of viruses etc on systems which don't receive updates any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app config, update the `<startup>` section so it looks like this

```
<configuration>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-configure-an-app-to-support-net-framework-4-or-4-5), this should attempt to run on .NET 4.x (built-in on all Windows 8 and later, installable on Windows XP, Vista & 7), and if it doesn't exist, attempt to run on .NET 2 or .NET 3.x (installable on Windows XP and later). Obviously, in an ideal world, you only need to concern with supported OSes (the oldest currently is Windows 8.1, that support 4.5.1 out of the box) that have Windows Update up and running (which should automatically install 4.8 by now)

Due to the difference between those runtimes, make sure you checked the behavior on the XP museum pieces, and if possible convince the management to just get rid of the XP box (plus Vista and 7, since they're no longer supported and liable to become an attack vector to other PC in the network)

Comment: Because of the huge differences between those two frameworks you could edit your answer and suggest testing the software in Windows XP machines and/or getting rid of those windows xp machines.

Comment: @Cleptus By "edit the question" do you mean to edit my answer?

Comment: Yup, sorry, I am sleepy

Answer (score 2):

Migrate your app to .NET Core / .NET5 and publish it as self-contained app, this way it will have the runtime with it on the client computer.

Maybe the hardest part you will encounter is a procedure to update your app after it was deployed, since ClickOnce does not exists in .NET Core / .NET5.

Comment: Unless the OS in question is Windows XP in which case ... I have no idea if it works at all

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/os-lifecycle-policy.md - It looks like the official minimum is Win 7 SP1.

Comment: Based on OP feedback, some of the computers run XP. Sadly this answer, useful in other cases, is no longer valid